# 301 Redirect not working in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm experiencing a frustrating problem with Apache rewrite rules and a 301 redirect.

We have an extensive list of RewriteRules, all of which work properly. Now I want anyone who goes to the root of our site to be redirected to another site. Here are the applicable rewrite rules in Apache:

```
RewriteRule "^/index.html" "http://newsite.somewhere.com" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "^/special-programs" "http://newsite.somewhere.com/special-programs/" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "^/prospective/" "http://newsite.somewhere.com/adms" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "^/current/careers/" "http://newsite.somewhere.com/careers" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "^/current/" "http://newsite.somewhere.com/current" [R=301,L]
```

Each of these redirects work except for the first one, the root of the site. It redirected using the defaults. However, as soon as I add [R=301,L] it simply stops redirecting all-together, while the other redirects continue to work properly. (A 301 redirect is a requirement; we can't use the default 302.)

I will add that there are many (dozens) redirects above these, but none of them involve the root of the site.

I've tried moving the RewriteRule to the top, to the bottom, and a few other places. No change. I'm reluctant to comment out the dozens of Rewrite rules above but will do so if last resort.

The rewrite rules are in a conf file under /etc/httpd/conf.d.

This seems like a straightforward scenario, so it is unclear to me why the 301 redirect isn't working. If anyone can provide some insight, it would be much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: rules don't have/need `"`-quotes. they're just characters, so your rules are expecting `http://example.com/"^index.html`, which is probably never going to happen.

Comment: What URL were your requesting? What does it mean to "redirected using the defaults"?

Comment: the quotes do not get in the way, they are parsed before they get to mod_rewrite.

Comment: By "defaults" I mean it redirects with a 302 if not otherwise specified.

Comment: Forgot to answer @covener's other question. The URL I'm requesting is www.someoldsite.com/index.html.  Ideally, any one going to www.someoldsite.com will be redirected to the new site. However, subdirectories on the old site still need to work without a redirect. That is, www.someoldsite.com should redirect with a 301, but www.someoldsite.com/foo shouldn't redirect at all.